# How to use AWS KMS Encryption in the node js SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I cannot figure out how to upload files into AWS S3 using KMS encryption from the Node JS SDK. I keep getting a 403: Access Denied error. I am able to get files from AWS S3 using KMS.

I am reusing most of the code from https://github.com/gilt/node-s3-encryption-client

## Main Class

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    crypt = require("./crypt"),
    kms,
    s3;

const metadataCipherAlgorithm = 'cipher-algorithm',
      metadataDecryptedEncoding = 'decrypted-encoding'
      metadataKmsKeyName = 'x-amz-key';


/**
 * Constructor - Initializes S3 sdk connection
 */
function S3FileStreamer(key, secret, region) {
    if (region) {
        AWS.config.region = region;
    }
    //set credentials if passed in
    if (key && secret) {
        AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: key, secretAccessKey: secret})
    }
    s3 = new AWS.S3({signatureVersion: "v4"});
    kms = new AWS.KMS({apiVersion: '2014-11-01'});
}

S3FileStreamer.prototype.uploadFile = function(bucket, key, kmsKey, filename, onComplete) {
    var params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
        Body: fs.readFileSync(filename),
        ContentType: getMimeType(filename)
    };

    params.KmsParams = {
        KeyId: kmsKey,
        KeySpec: 'AES_256'
    }

    kmsUpload(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) onComplete(err, null);
        else {
            onComplete(err, data);
        }
    });
};

function kmsUpload(params, callback) {
  var kmsParams = params.KmsParams
  if (kmsParams && kmsParams.KeyId) {
    kms.generateDataKey(kmsParams, function(err, kmsData) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err, null);
      } else {
        var helper = new crypt.Helper(kmsData.Plaintext.toString('base64'), {algorithm: params.CipherAlgorithm, decryptedEncoding: params.DecryptedEncoding});
        params.Body = helper.encrypt(params.Body);
        params.Metadata = params.Metadata || {};
        params.Metadata[metadataKmsKeyName] = kmsData.CiphertextBlob.toString('base64');
        if (params.CipherAlgorithm) params.Metadata[metadataCipherAlgorithm] = params.CipherAlgorithm;
        if (params.DecryptedEncoding) params.Metadata[metadataDecryptedEncoding] = params.DecryptedEncoding;
        putObject(params, callback);
      }
    })
  } else {
    putObject(params, callback);
  }
}

function putObject(params, callback) {
  delete params.KmsParams;
  delete params.CipherAlgorithm;
  delete params.DecryptedEncoding;
  s3.putObject(params, callback);
}
```

## Crypt class

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

/*
  options:
    algorithm: Anything from crypto.getCiphers()
    decryptedEncoding: 'utf8', 'ascii', or 'binary'
    outputEncoding: 'binary', 'base64', or 'hex'
 */
exports.Helper = function(password, options) {
  this.password = password;
  options = options || {};
  this.algorithm = options.algorithm || 'aes-256-cbc';
  this.decryptedEncoding = options.decryptedEncoding || 'utf8';
  this.encryptedEncoding = options.encryptedEncoding || 'base64';
}

exports.Helper.prototype.encrypt = function(unencrypted) {
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher(this.algorithm, this.password);
  return cipher.update(unencrypted, this.decryptedEncoding, this.encryptedEncoding) + cipher.final(this.encryptedEncoding);
}

exports.Helper.prototype.decrypt = function(encrypted) {
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(this.algorithm, this.password);
  return decipher.update(encrypted, this.encryptedEncoding, this.decryptedEncoding) + decipher.final(this.decryptedEncoding);
}
```

Is there something I am missing here, an extra metadata tag that needs to be set?

Is the keyId parameter that is passed to the kms `generateDataKey` method supposed to be in some sort of unique format? I am just simply passing in my key.

Comment: Where are you reading the file from?.Check if you have permission to read the file from the source at first. Then probably check if the role you are using has update-write permissions on the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 3):

While the other answer about checking permissions is undoubtedly correct.  I had a hard time finding a good example of how to decode S3 objects using the AES GCM encryption algorithm.  I managed to get this code to work based on the aws ruby sdk (as I found the node-s3-encryption-client a little old).

```
/**
 * Decrypt s3 file data
 * @param  {object}   objectData result of s3 get call
 * @param  {Function} callback   function(err, data) returns error or decrypted data
 */
function decrypt(objectData, callback) {
    var metadata = objectData.Metadata || {};
    var kmsKeyBase64 = metadata['x-amz-key-v2'];
    var iv = metadata['x-amz-iv'];
    var tagLen = (metadata['x-amz-tag-len'] || 0)/8;
    var algo = metadata['x-amz-cek-alg'];
    var encryptionContext = JSON.parse(metadata['x-amz-matdesc']);

    switch (algo) {
        case 'AES/GCM/NoPadding':
            algo = 'aes-256-gcm';
            break;
        case 'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding':
            algo = 'aes-256-cbc';
            break;
        default:
            callback(new Error('Unsupported algorithm: ' + algo), null);
            return;
    }

    if (typeof (kmsKeyBase64) === 'undefined') {
        callback(new Error('Missing key in metadata'), null);
        return;
    }

    var kmsKeyBuffer = new Buffer(kmsKeyBase64, 'base64');
    kms.decrypt({
        CiphertextBlob: kmsKeyBuffer,
        EncryptionContext: encryptionContext
    }, function(err, kmsData) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algo,
                                                   kmsData.Plaintext,
                                                   new Buffer(iv, 'base64'));

            if (tagLen !== 0) {
                // the tag is appended to the data buffer
                var tag = objectData.Body.slice(-tagLen);
                decipher.setAuthTag(tag);
            }
            var data = objectData.Body.slice(0,-tagLen);

            var dec = decipher.update(data, 'binary', 'utf8');
            dec += decipher.final('utf8');

            console.log("Decoded:", dec);
            callback(null, dec);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help. I figured out the solution to my question.

I went back to using just using the aws-sdk node module and took out all the code I got from the node-s3-encryption-client module.

All I needed to do in order to successfully upload a file into Amazon S3 using KMS encryption was to add two parameters before passing my params object to the putObject method. These parameters were `ServerSideEncryption` and `SSEKMSKeyId` as shown below. It now works!

```
var params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
    Body: fs.readFileSync(filename),
    ContentType: getMimeType(filename),
    ServerSideEncryption: 'aws:kms',
    SSEKMSKeyId: kmsKey
};

s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
});
```